# How to make an audio file player that plays a random file each time

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that plays a random WAV file each time the button is pressed. I have everything set up except for how to make it play a random file. How would I make it play a random file from the selection of the two files I have?

```
public class joeyMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI g = new GUI();
    g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    g.setSize(300,200);
    g.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{

static void PlaySound(File Sound){
    try{
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound));
        clip.start();

        Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

private JButton r;

public GUI(){
    super("AreaFinder");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(800, 800);

    r = new JButton("Random Joey Quote");
    r.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            File Joey1 = new File("video1.WAV");
            File Joey2 = new File("video2.WAV"); 
            PlaySound(Joey1);
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    });
    add(r);
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range

Comment: How do I use Random to randomize WAV files, not numbers?

Comment: you have different options .for example add files to a array and then generate random number between 0 and array.length-1 .then you can select a random file

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in array and then randomly select one of them.

```
File[] arr = new File[] {new File("video1.WAV"), new File("video2.WAV")};
Random random = new Random();
PlaySound(arr[random.nextInt(arr.length)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ArrayList` with all the files added to it. Once done you can use the following code mentioned by Fast Snail to generate a random number

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```

and get the random file from the array list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Math.random() function:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
File Joey1 = new File("video1.WAV");
File Joey2 = new File("video2.WAV");
int rnd2 = (int) (2 * Math.random());
if (rnd2==0) PlaySound(Joey1);
else PlaySound(Joey2);
}
```